# Spark does not load all rows from CSV file

Tags: csv, apache-spark, dataframe, load, missing-data

I'm trying to load data from a csv file which contains arround 1 million rows, when i print a count of my dataset, i get only 483414 rows.

Here is how i load my data:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset=sparkSession.read().options(fileOptions).csv(filePath);
dataset.count(); //<-- 483414 rows instead of 1066879
```

file options:

> "header"=> "true" "delimiter" => "µ" "charset" => "iso-8859-1"

I'm using spark 2.1.0 and hdp 2.6. and java 1.8. spark is submitted with from masternode (client mode).
I have no errors or warning when subitting the job.
**I tried the load using panda, i get the whole data (1066879 rows).**
Do you have any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Before performing the `count` on your dataset, can you please do something like `dataset.rdd.first()` just so you can see if the rows are being delimited the way you want?
If you could show us a couple of rows, that would be great

Comment: Yes the data are well formatted. i am able to print the schema with 95 columns and print first rows. everything is ok except not getting all the data from the CSV

Comment: Okay, got it. Another idea: instead of using `dataset.count()`, please use `dataset.rdd.count()` (might take a bit longer). Please tell me if you get the same result.

Comment: Probably is a problem with schema or encoding.  If you think your data is well formatted use mode failfast and process will fail when a line can't be read.

Comment: I tried the count using rdd it gaves the same result as dataset count.
Using the failfast mode and running the count indeed get errors `Malformed line in FAILFAST mode`. I have some long string, is that wihch causing the errors?

Comment: Truly rows were malformed. data are changed during a file transfer from one server to other. I recopied the file and now it works. Thanks all